# Correctly deleting the pointers of a 3D matrix

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix, dynamic-memory-allocation

I wrote a program to create a 3D matrix (or multidimensional matrix), in which all the parameters (rows, columns, all are variable). The type of matrix I am working with looks something like this:

[image: 3D Matrix]

The program is working as intended. But I don't know if deleting the pointers is correctly freeing up memory. Am I deleting the pointers correctly?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int  vol;                   
    cout << "enter number of 2d arrays(vol value)" <<endl;
    cin >> vol;
    int row[10];
    cout<< "enter number of rows in each vol" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < vol ; i++)
    {
        cin >> row[i];
    }

    //================ Entering col for each rown in each vol  ================//
    int **col;
    col = new int *[vol];

    for (int i = 0; i < vol ; i++)
    {
        *(col+i) = new int [row[i]];
        for (int j = 0; j < row[i] ; j++)
        {
            cout<< "enter columns of " << j << "th row " <<" of vol " << i  <<" :  ";
            cin>>*(*(col+i)+j);
        }

    }

    //======= Printing the value of each col for each rown in each vol =======//
    cout<< "entered values are \n \n" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < vol; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < row[i]; j++)
        {
            cout<< *(*(col + i) + j);
            cout << "\t";
        }

        cout<< "\n" << endl;
    }

    //========================Creation of 3d matrix===========================//
    int ***p;

    p = new int **[vol];            //creating number of vol
    for (int i = 0; i < vol ; i++)  //creating rows for each vol
    {
        *(p + i) = new int *[row[i]];
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < vol ; j++)  //creating 1d array for each row
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < row[j] ; k++)
        {
            *(*(p + j) + k) = new int [*(*(col + j) + k)];
        }
    }

    //============Entering all the values in the 3d variable matrix===========//
    cout<< "entering elements into 3d matrix" << endl;
    cout << "enter all the values \n \n" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < vol ; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < row[i] ; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < *(*(col + i) + j) ; k++)
            {
                cout<< "enter the value in col " <<k <<", of row " << j<< ", of vol " << i << " : "<< endl;
                cin >> *(*(*(p + i) + j) + k);
            }
        }
    }

    //============Printing all the values in the 3d variable matrix===========//
    cout<< "Lets print all the values in 3d matrix \n\n" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < vol; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < row[i]; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < *(*(col + i) + j); k++)
            {
                cout<< *(*(*(p + i) + j) + k);
                cout << "\t";
            }

            cout<< " \n" << endl;
        }

        cout<< "\n\n============================" << endl;
    }

    //======================= deleting all pointers ========================//

    //Deleting the col pointer
    for (int i = 0; i < vol ; i++)
    {
        delete[] col[i];
    }

    delete[] col;

    //Deleting the p pointer
    for (int i = 0; i < vol ; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < row[vol] ; j++)
        {
            delete[] p[j];          //deleting the last arrays
        }
        delete[] p[i];
    }
    delete []p;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Quick sanity check shows your `new` and `delete`s match up (same number, all use the `[]` form).  The best thing to do though is run your program through a leak detector (e.g., `valgrind`) since that'll give you a definite answer.

Comment: What you really want are smart pointers.  Go search for std::unique_ptr and std::shared_ptr; then all your deletes can be ... deleted

Comment: Aside: you may wish to put it on the sister site https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to get feedback on your style

Comment: The term you're looking for here is _array_, not matrix.

Comment: When it gets to this level of array indexing, I tend to put it into a flat array and add get/set with the proper indexes to do my work.  I hate multi-level allocations like this.  Error prone and wasteful.

Comment: I know. But this is part of my syllebus @MichaelDorgan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to respect the way of deletion as much as the way of creation so you can do:

```
//Deleting the p pointer
for ( int i = 0; i < vol ; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < row[vol] ; j++)
        delete[] p[i][j];
    delete[] p[i];
}

delete[] p;
```